# how to redirect clean url of htacces in my site?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have search many times but not find correct answer

i want to this

my url is domain.com/privacy.php

and i want to domain.com/privacy/

it's possible if yes please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

use something like

```
Options +FollowSymlinks All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^privacy.php$ privacy/
```

Comment: @RohitAzad Then check few thing, check the rewrite_module enabled of not in you httpd.conf file, second is the `RewriteBase` is correct??

Answer (score 0):

To re-write the URL:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
######
############
############
######
RewriteRule ^privacy/ privacy.php [NC]
```

Update: Do you want privacy.php to redirect you to the /privacy too?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Not sure what you mean but this is my answer to my guess at what you mean